# A string to upper AND lower

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make the first line upper and the second line lower with this code, but I have no idea how I use both at the same string.. As you see at the code, I already have it at upper.
All the help will be appreciated!

```
example_string = "This is the first line\nand this is the second line "
new_string = example_string.splitlines()
print(example_string.upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
example_string = "This is the first line\nand this is the second line "
new_string = example_string.splitlines()
print(new_string[0].upper(), new_string[1].lower())
```

Comment: Hehe, yes it was. You are welcome :-) Please accept the answer and maybe consider upvoting others who made effort to help you!

Answer (score 0):

From `splitlines()` you recieve list of lines, so use indexing to get right line, and `upper()` or `lower()` to change it.

```
example_string = "This is the first line\nand this is the second line "
new_string = example_string.splitlines()
print(new_string[0].upper())
print(new_string[1].lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might have more than two lines in your input and only the first line should be converted to upper case.

Here are a few tricks you might use:

```
converted_string = '\n'.join([new_string[0].upper()]+
                             [x.lower() for x in new_string[1:]])
print(converted_string)
```

First note that the result of `splitlines()` is an array of strings where each element is a separate line. In order to turn it back into a single string you might want to use the `str.join(iterable)` function.

This function returns a concatenation of the elements of its argument delimited by the `str` that it is called on.

That is `'\n'.join(new_string)` would be equivalent to the original `example_string`.

Now to apply `str.lower()` function to every element of the slice of a list you could use list comprehension:

```
   [x.lower() for x in new_string[1:]]
```